# How to compare a substring with a list of elements in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, substring

I am trying to compare substring from a string that I am getting from reading a .txt file and matching it with an element of the list.

String from the .txt file is as follows:

```
 1. Blood 75.6 gm% 12-14    
 2. Rash 15.4 tm/m 54-89
```

I have a list called data which includes the words that are occuring as a first word in the string.
So,

```
data = ['blood', 'Rash']

f = open('my.txt', r)
for x in f:
    if x.find(str(data)):
    # Do something
```

How do I match these both and then do my operations on it?

Comment: So in other words, you want to determine if each line read from the text file contains either "blood" or "rash"?

Comment: @PaulBrink Yes. Each line has a keyword that I am trying to match by defining it into a list and it is always the first word occurring in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("my.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       for i in data:
           if i in line:
               do_operation()
```

Is this what you were asking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) operator which will return true if any word in the line of `f` matches any `string` in `data`.

```py
f = open('my.txt', r)
for x in f:
    if any(y in x for y in data):
        #Do operation
```

or if you want to check that every line contains at least one `string` in `data`. You can use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) operator which will return true if all lines contain a `string` in `data`:

```py
f = open('my.txt', r)

if all(any(y in x for y in data) for x in f):
   #Do operation
```